# Xamarin Forms UIWebview text is very small

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview, uiwebview

I have a Xamarin forms app with webviews on different screens. Suddenly, my font on the webview is very small on iOS. On the image attached, the text was occupying almost the entire screen. Now it's less than half.

I don't have a custom rendered for iOS. On Android is working correctly. Anyone has ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using **UIWebView** in Xamarin.iOS , you can use `EvaluateJavascript` to modify font size of Text .

```
webView.LoadFinished += WebView_LoadFinished;

private void WebView_LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var webView = sender as UIWebView;
    string fontSize = "100%"; // 100% is the size of font
    string stringFont = String.Format(@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '{0}'", fontSize);
    webView.EvaluateJavascript(stringFont);
}
```

If in Forms , you need to use **WkWebViewRenderer** to implement it :

```
this.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegat();

public class NavigationDelegat : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    public override void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)
    {
        string fontSize = "100%"; // 100% is the size of font
        string stringsss = String.Format(@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '{0}'", fontSize);
        WKJavascriptEvaluationResult handler = (NSObject result, NSError err) => {
            if (err != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(err);
            }
            if (result != null)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
        };
        webView.EvaluateJavaScript(stringsss, handler);
        //base.DidFinishNavigation(webView, navigation);
    }
}
```

**However** :I think this should be solved by modifying html file . Generally , webpage 
when matching iOS and Android need to do something about style of html . Because iOS just show with default size of font the same with Android , there are some different between them when showing . The html designer need to consider it can be used in iOS or Android perfectly.

===============================Update========================================

> I am creating/pushing the HTML content into the webviews.

if using `Html` string content when load webview , you can add a header style before the content `Html` .

As follow :

```
string headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'><style>img{max-width:100%}</style></header>";
string finalHtml = headerString + baseHtml ; //baseHtml is current loaded Html
...
```

For example , you can modify the value of `initial-scale` inside the `headerString` .Follow is the sample effect :

```
string headerString = "<header><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=2.0, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'><style>img{max-width:100%}</style></header>";
string bodyString = "<html><body><h1>Xamarin.Forms</h1><p>Welcome to WebView.</p></body></html>";
string finalHtml = headerString + bodyString;
...
```

***initial-scale=1.0*** :

[image: initial-scale=1.0]

***initial-scale=2.0*** :

[image: initial-scale=2.0]

Comment: I am creating/pushing the HTML content into the webviews. I am not loading it from a  webpage. Should I just set the font on the text on the body tag using styles ?

Comment: @sebastian.roibu If using HTML content , there will be a easy way . I will update the answer , you can have a try .

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I figured out the scale factor and remove the user-scalable=no because I want the user to have the ability to zoom.

Comment: @sebastian.roibu Yeah , you can custom the header style to fit the needs .